# How do I run a single job for pushes and a `matrix` job for schedules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Say, I have this job configuration in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, making use of [parallel matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs) jobs:

```yaml
job:
  image: $IMAGE
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ARCHIVE: ["archive-a.tgz", "archive-b.tgz" ]
        IMAGE: ["image1", "image2"]
  script:
    - echo $ARCHIVE $IMAGE
```

How do I need to change this so that:

- for pushes, only **one** job is run (`archive-a.tgz` + `image1`)
- for schedules, the **four** jobs are run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by using rules: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

like:

```yaml
job:
  image: $IMAGE
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ARCHIVE: ["archive-a.tgz", "archive-b.tgz" ]
        IMAGE: ["image1", "image2"]
  script:
    - echo $ARCHIVE $IMAGE
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $ARCHIVE == "archive-a.tgz" && $IMAGE == "image1"'
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
```

although this is not really a beautiful solution, it works for your case - you can also try to negate it and use `when: never`. Based on the `rules` definition this should also work:

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in order until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the configuration.

```yaml
job:
  image: $IMAGE
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ARCHIVE: ["archive-a.tgz", "archive-b.tgz" ]
        IMAGE: ["image1", "image2"]
  script:
    - echo $ARCHIVE $IMAGE
  rules:
    - if: '$ARCHIVE == "archive-a.tgz" && $IMAGE == "image1"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Disclaimer: the snippets i provided are not tested!

A third option would be an intermediate job holding the logic and having two dedicated jobs with own rules like and providing the variables. There are a lot of ways to achieve this, and you have to see which one is the best for your case.

```yaml
.job:
  image: $IMAGE
  script:
    - echo $ARCHIVE $IMAGE

matrix:
  extends: .job
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ARCHIVE: ["archive-a.tgz", "archive-b.tgz" ]
        IMAGE: ["image1", "image2"]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"

push:
  extends: .job
  variables:
    ARCHIVE: "archive-a.tgz"
    IMAGE: "image1"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

Comment: Thanks! The third option did suit me best, so I have now a base template job and two actual workers which are extending it .